# Java program which opens a file containing integers, and print, counts and displays in output dialog box.(Using JOptionPane)

Tags: java, string, while-loop, filereader, joptionpane

I have to create a java program which opens a file containing integers. An input dialog box asks the use the name of the input file, and then an output dialog box shows the values read  from the data file, each on a different line, and then the number of values from the file. I am confused
as to what is missing from my code. The input dialog box appears but I am completely stuck after that.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class prob2
{
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        String name, out="", out2="" ;
        int quantity=0, val; 
        name=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the file to be opened: ");
        Scanner inputFile= new Scanner(new FileReader(name));

        while(inputFile.hasNextInt());
        {
            val=inputFile.nextInt();
            out= val+"\n";
            quantity++; 
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
        val + quantity);
        inputFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (inputFile.hasNextInt());` <-- wonder what that little `;` will do 

Answer (score 1):

Your initial problem is right here

```
while(inputFile.hasNextInt()); // <- Or here actually...
```

This is basically setting up an infinite loop instead of executing the block of ode you want

Start by removing the `;` at the end of the line...

```
while(inputFile.hasNextInt())
{
    val=inputFile.nextInt();
    out= val+"\n";
    quantity++; 
}
```

Once you've that, you will to change

```
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            val + quantity);
```

to

```
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            out + quantity);
```

to overcome the compiler error

And finally, you will need to change...

```
out = val + "\n";
```

in your `while-loop` to

```
out += val + "\n";
```

so that you are actually concatenating the result

(and yes, we should be using `StringBuilder`, but I think we can let that one slide for now)

Comment: thank you so much! whoops stupid mistakes of me, but once i made those edits, the output dialog box only prints the first value from the text file I chose, and then the quantity on the next line. how do i get it to print ALL the values from the file and not just the last value from my file??

Comment: *"whoops stupid mistakes of me"* - Welcome to my every day . *"the output dialog box only prints the first value from the text file"* - I made an amendment to the answer which should solve it, see the last 5 lines or so.

Comment: you are an absolute life saver, thank you so much!! class hadn't touched upon StringBuilder yet and I just couldn't figure it out. it worked perfectly

Comment: You don't "need" `StringBuilder` and given all the other issues you seem to be having, it won't provide you any additional benefit - just understand that `StringBuilder` will provide you with a performance boost over performing `String` concatenation within a loop like you're doing

Comment: I'm still new to learning java, but thank you, you were a lot of help! I'll learn StringBuilder and figure out how to use that next, I was just trying to use what I knew already to figure out this program 

Answer (score 0):

You have to collect the input you are reading in and that you want to later print.

For example by creating a StringBuilder instance and appending the content you wish to present to the user.

When you are done reading you pass *builder.toString()* to *another* option pain as message.

Comment: thank you for your help! i hadn't yet learnt StringBuilder, so I was trying to build my  program with what I already knew :(

Comment: Sure. In case this works for you, please consider accepting the answer at some point.